# Procedurally Generated History

Tags: simulation, history, procedural-generation

I want to create a procedurally generated history system for a game I am making, somewhat similar to Dwarf Fortress even though that's really complex. I have taken a stab at it and it didn't turn out too well. So I was wondering how should I go about creating this system? How do I make civilizations be allies, enemies, trade, go to war, control population, farm for themselves, etc. Again this doesn't have to be realistic, just make an interesting story for the player to discover about the world they are playing in.

Thanks!

Comment: You have asked how to do a lot of different things at once, and I think the answer to each would depend on how the rest of your game works. I would recommend choosing one of those things and implementing  it first and then move to the next one, looking for places to tie things together as you go. You might want to give each of those systems a flat die roll implementation to get started (if there are `n` choices, pick one completely at random.)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start by looking at graphs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory

Peace/war status mostly depends on competition for resources and their initial proximity to the resources and their skills. You mind find some inspiration in biology (predator/prey).

An already large civ. will negotiate less and assimilate more.
A first step is always to trade, then control more trade, then conquer to completely own the trade (then collapse).
Think about a few real world history cases and try to model according to that. Each civ. ultimately computes a cost score and tries to optimize gains while reducing losses.